# How to get the response data in laravel unit testing

Tags: laravel, unit-testing

I have been trying to work with laravel unit testing.
What I wanted was how to get the response data of original.

```
public function testProducts()
{
    $response=$this->call('GET','/products',['cat','all']);

    // dd($response);

    $data = $response->getData();
    //  dd($data);
}
```

When I dd in the first case it shows me HTML content. What I want to be shown is the real content with array. What should I do ?

Comment: what real content? you are returning a view from the route?

Comment: Sorry due to being new in laravel testing. No I don't return a view. I return  an array with products.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to get the data out. Instead use `assertJson()`. You simply build your `JSON` structure as a `PHP` associate array and it will assert it by `JSON` encoding it.

```
$response->assertJson([
    [
        'name' => 'Iphone',
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create different product first on the same test case and then check with assertJSon

```
factory(product::class)->create(['name' => 'Cat']);
factory(product::class)->create(['name' => 'all']);
factory(product::class)->create(['name' => 'other']);



$response = $this->json('GET', '/api/products', ['Cat','all'])
    ->assertStatus(200)
    ->assertJson([
        [ 'name' => 'cat'],['name'=>'all']
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

$response->viewData() may be the method you're looking for.

If, for example, you do a dd($response) and see that you have an instance of an object "model", and that object has a field "column", you'd do:

$val = $response->viewData("model")->column;

to get the value of that property.